# I am using StackExhange.Redis.Extensions.Core nuget package in .net core. I want to know where exactly is the connection gets opened to Redis?

Tags: c#, json, .net, redis, stackexchange.redis

I am using StackExhange.Redis.Extensions.Core nuget package in .net core. I want to know where exactly is the connection gets opened to Redis ?

Here is my code :

Here is me appsettings :

```json
    "Redis": {
    "Password": "xyz123", 
    "AllowAdmin": true,
    "Ssl": true,
    "KeepAlive": 180,
    "ConnectTimeout": 5000, //Timeout for connecting to redis
    "ConnectRetry": 2,
    "PoolSize": 1,
    "User": "appuser",
    "SyncTimeout": 5000, 
    "AsyncTimeout": 5000, 
    "Database": 0,
    "Hosts": [
      {
        "Host": "cluster.payment-redis.hshwxw12.use1.cache.amazonaws.com",
        "Port": "6379"
      }
    ]
  }
```

My code:

```cs
var redisConfiguration = Configuration.GetSection("Redis").Get<RedisConfiguration>();
services.AddStackExchangeRedisExtensions<NewtonsoftSerializer>(redisConfiguration);   

private readonly IRedisClient _redisClient;
private readonly ILogger<ICacheService> _logger;
private IRedisDatabase _redisDatabase;
private bool IsDisposed = false;
public CacheService(IRedisClient redisClient, ILogger<ICacheService> _logger)
{
    this._redisClient = redisClient;
    this._logger = _logger;
}

private IRedisDatabase Database
{
    get
    {
        if (_redisDatabase == null)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation(_redisClient.ToString());
            _redisDatabase = _redisClient.GetDefaultDatabase();
        }
        return _redisDatabase;
    }
}
public async Task<(bool isSuccess, string errorMessage)> SetAsync<T>(string key, T data, TimeSpan? expiry)
{
    bool isSuccess = false;
    string errorMessage = string.Empty;
    if (expiry == null)
    {
        expiry = TimeSpan.FromHours(1);
    }
    try
    {
        string jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);

        await Database.AddAsync(key, jsonData, (TimeSpan)expiry).ConfigureAwait(false);
        isSuccess = true;

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        errorMessage = ex?.Message;
        _logger.LogError(ex?.Message);
    }
    return (isSuccess, errorMessage);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Redis connection will open in the below condition.

await Database.AddAsync(key, jsonData, (TimeSpan)expiry).ConfigureAwait(false);